# axios.post update my mongodb but returns undefined using async await in react

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

[image: this is my debugging pic]

[image: this is my callig to axios]

[image: calling the above function using async and await in middleware]

i would like to mention that i used postmen and got results as expected so no problem with server side. and also it does update  my db but doesnt send the results;
(so whene i debug it never reaches line 10 looks like it stoped execution , i tried to console. log (data) and nothing show up... )
thanks in advenced!!!

Comment: In your first screen shot, it will naturally show undefined because you did not use `await`. You will be able to see the proper response in your 3rd screenshot line number 9 `{data}`

Comment: right! but whene i debug it never reaches line 10 looks like it stoped execution , i tried to console. log (data) and nothing show up...

Comment: you need to make it an async function and use `return axios.post(.....)` directly. You need to make it an async function because in your midAdduser you are using await api.addUser.

Comment: hey thanks a lot:) but it still not working... maybe i didnt get you right ,did you meant the code to be like so: `export const addUser = async (user) => {
    return axios.post(`${URL}/addUser`, user);`
};